# Azure Synapse loading: Split large compress files to smaller compressed files

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm receiving this recommendation from Azure Synapse.

Recommendation details
We have detected that you can increase load throughput by splitting your compressed files that are staged in your storage account. A good rule of thumb is to split compressed files into 60 or more to maximize the parallelism of your load. [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/guidance-for-loading-data#preparing-data-in-azure-storage)

Looking at Azure's docs, this is the recommendation.

```
Preparing data in Azure Storage
To minimize latency, colocate your storage layer and your SQL pool.

When exporting data into an ORC File Format, you might get Java out-of-memory errors when there are large text columns. To work around this limitation, export only a subset of the columns.

All file formats have different performance characteristics. For the fastest load, use compressed delimited text files. The difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16 performance is minimal.

Split large compressed files into smaller compressed files.
```

What I'm trying to understand is how can I split a large compress files into smaller compress files? Is there an option for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may checkout this article [How to maximize COPY load throughput with file splits](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/how-to-maximize-copy-load-throughput-with-file-splits/ba-p/1314474).

It’s recommended to load multiple files at once for parallel processing and maximizing bulk loading performance with SQL pools using the COPY statement.

File-splitting guidance is outlined in the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#what-is-the-file-splitting-guidance-for-the-copy-command-loading-csv-files) and this blog covers how to easily split CSV files residing in your data lake using Azure Data Factory Mapping data flows within your data pipeline.

Comment: Yes, Polybase and Copy Command are two most prominent methods for performing high throughput loads from Azure Storage to Azure Synapse. The COPY command will have better performance depending on your workload. For best loading performance, consider splitting your input into multiple files when loading CSV.

Comment: many thanks! I'm currently using POLYBASE. Does it mean I should switch to COPY for a better performance?

Comment: Yes, you can switch to Copy command for better performace.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.